A local sort-of Dedekind criterion
In class I have seen that for $L/K$ a finite extension of number fields with $L=K(a)$ where $a$ has min poly $f$. Then for a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ we have that
$$L \otimes K_\mathfrak{p} \cong \prod_{\mathfrak{P}|\mathfrak{p}} L_\mathfrak{P}$$.
Where subscript prime denotes completion.
After proving this my instructor remarked that this relates the how $\mathfrak{p}O_L$ factorises and how $f$ factorises in $K_\mathfrak{p}$.
I was wondering how to make this more precise. I can see (from the proof) that
$$L \otimes K_\mathfrak{p} \cong \prod_{i} K_\mathfrak{p}[X]/(f_i) \cong \prod_{\mathfrak{P}|\mathfrak{p}} L_\mathfrak{P}$$
where $f_i$ are the factors of $f$ in $K_\mathfrak{p}$. From this we can deduce that the number of distinct primes lying above $\mathfrak{p}$ is equal to the number of factors of $f$ (already distinct as separable).
I was wondering if anything more precise can be said? For example can we say anything about the ramification indices. For example in dedekinds criterion we use the degree of the polynomials to do this. Does anything like that work here? Although this may be optimistic as we don't have the coprime index assumption on the ring of integers.

You can still say a number of things:

The ramification index $e_i$ of $\mathfrak{P}/\mathfrak{p}$ is the ramification index of the local field extension $L_{\mathfrak{P}}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}$.
The inertia degree $f_i$ of $\mathfrak{P}/\mathfrak{p}$ is the inertia degree of the local field extension $L_{\mathfrak{P}}/K_{\mathfrak{p}}$.
Putting these these two observations together with the fact you note, you get the formula $[L : K] = \sum_{\mathfrak{P}_i/\mathfrak{p}} e_if_i$. If $L : K$ is Galois, then this becomes $[L : K] = efg$, where all $g$ primes lying above $\mathfrak{p}$ have the same ramification index $e$ and the same inertia degree $f$. You can prove this formula by dimension counting on either side of the tensor product formula.

The first two points might seem like trivial observations, depending on your definitions, but they can be genuinely useful. It is often easier to determine splitting behavior of primes by passing to the completion(s), since you have access to things like Hensel's lemma and valuations are simpler to work with. Another practical reason is that the Dedekind-Kummer theorem is often unpleasant to apply in practice because not all rings of integers are monogenic and you need to worry about coprimality, but this difficulty completely disappears in the local fields approach.

As a concrete example, to prove $2$ splits completely in $\mathbf Q(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $x^3 - x^2 - 2x - 8$ (which is irreducible over $\mathbf Q$ since it is irreducible mod $3$), this polynomial splits over $\mathbf Q_2$ since it has $3$ roots in $\mathbf Z_2$ by Hensel's lemma: $|f(\alpha)|_2 < |f'(\alpha)|_2^2$ when $\alpha$ is $0$, $1$, and $2$.
